# Change JUnit report path

Tags: android, gradle

By default the JUnit reports are generated at `build/reports/tests/testDebugUnitTest` and `build/reports/tests/testReleaseUnitTest`

How I can modify my gradle file so I can change this location?

Comment: Any idea guys?...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can configure the html and xml output explicitly per task:

```
test {
    reports.junitXml.destination = file("$buildDir/xml")
    reports.html.destination = file("$buildDir/html")
}
```